# Existence of a set of binary vectors which fulfill certain constraints

Tags: combinatorics, vectors, binary, constraints

The following problem seems somewhat abstract but it would be nice to get it (dis)proven. Assume we are given a set $\mathcal B$ of $n$ binary vectors $\boldsymbol b_1,\dots,\boldsymbol b_n$, each of dimension $2^n-3$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol b_i\in \{0,1\}^{2^n-3}, \ 1\le i\le n.
\end{align}
The assumption is now that there is **no** set $\mathcal B$ s.t. the following constraints are fulfilled:
\begin{align}
\langle \boldsymbol b_i,\boldsymbol b_i\rangle&\overset{!}{=}2^{n-1}-1, \ 1\le i\le n, \tag{1} \\
\langle \boldsymbol b_i,\boldsymbol b_j\rangle&\overset{!}{=}2^{n-2}-1, \ i\neq j. \tag{2}
\end{align}
In words, $(1)$ ensures that every vector has exactly $2^{n-1}-1$ *ones* and $(2)$ ensures that each vector pair has exactly $2^{n-2}-1$ *ones* in common.

For $n=2$ it is true, since for $\mathcal B=\{\boldsymbol b_1,\boldsymbol b_2\}$, $\boldsymbol b_i\in\{0,1\}$, we only have $1$ possibility, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal B =\{0,1\},
$$
which does not adhere $(1)$.

It is also true for $n=3$, since if $(1)$ is adhered, then every $\boldsymbol b_i$ is of dimension $5$ with $3$ *ones*. If we now take two vectors $\boldsymbol b_1$, $\boldsymbol b_2$ which adhere $(2)$, then the vector $\boldsymbol b_1 + \boldsymbol b_2$ has no *zero* entries. If any $\boldsymbol b_3$ adheres $(1)$ it has $3$ *ones* and thus has to have more than a single *one* in common with $\boldsymbol b_1$ or $\boldsymbol b_2$, which violates $(2)$.

Intuitively it seems to me that this principle is easily extendable to any $n>3$, either through induction or maybe just the pigeonhole principle, but I cannot figure out how. There may also be a nice counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a counter example for n=4:

[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12}, {3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 12}])

Where I only wrote the indices of the 'true' (or 1) entries for each vector. So, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} could also be written as
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Cheers